# Better method to store user credentials

Tags: android, iphone, web-applications, curl, session-cookies

Ok, so I am trying to develop a mobile website application for the iPhone and Android. Currently my site uses cURL to log the user into the other site. I have a PHP script that creates a cookie based on the username of the user. cURL then places the info into that cookie. The cookie is stored on my site's host.

Basically this mobile site I am creating is suppose to allow users to log into a forum that I developed this for (site owner would not allow me to create a mobile version on their site so needed to do it on mine). Then once they log in they can read posts and reply to them. When it goes to read a thread needs to load the cookie, as well as when they try to make a post.

How can I get the cookie to save to the users phone rather than my server? The reason I ask is, I'd like it so my host doesn't get filled up with dozens of text files with credentials of users (which I don't want to see so I am not phishing).

I want it so the user signs in, cookie gets saved to the phone. They want to read a post the phone pulls up that cookie. They want to post, phone pulls up the cookie.

I looked into PHP setcookie() function, wasn't sure if that is what I needed.

Any help provided will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a cookie on the server side that cookie gets sent to the client (your phone in this case) via something called HTTP Headers.  There is a HTTP Header with the name "Set-Cookie" and a Value of the cookie.  When the browser makes a request to the server in the future, its expected to give that value back in a HTTP Header called "Cookie"

So, if you want to set a cookie and use that cookie its a matter of getting the cookie from your request, storing it somewhere safe, and giving it back in future requests.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Here is a simple Authentication method that takes an url, a username and a password and returns the cookie value.

```
static public String authenticate(String service_url, String username, String password) throws IOException
{
    if (username == null || password == null)
        throw new IOException();

    String charset = "UTF-8";       
    URL url = new URL(service_url);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset="+charset);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setReadTimeout(5000); // 2 second timeout.

    String query = String.format("Email=%s&Password=%s",
            URLEncoder.encode(username, charset),
            URLEncoder.encode(password, charset));

    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
         output = connection.getOutputStream();
         output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
    } finally {
         if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    }

    connection.getInputStream();

    List<String> cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
    if (cookies == null)
        throw new IOException();

    for (String cookie : cookies)
    {
        if (cookie.startsWith("authcookie"))
            return cookie; // this is the only correct path out.
    }
    throw new IOException();
}
```

Example HTTPGET, note the http header to add the cookie value back to requests.

```
public static InputStream getDataFromHTTP(String url, String authenticationCookie, String     mimetype) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{       
    DefaultHttpClient client = getHttpClient();     

    if (client == null)
        throw new IOException("Cant getHttpClient()");

    if (url == null)
        throw new IOException("URL is null");

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    httpget.addHeader("Accept", mimetype);
    httpget.addHeader("Cookie", authenticationCookie);      
    httpget.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);

    InputStream instream = response.getEntity().getContent();
    Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");

    if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
        instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
    }

    return instream;
}
```